# Finding all ASP.NET MVC public action methods that accept a string as a parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reflection

I am attempting to use [Nitriq](http://www.nitriq.com/) to get a list of all of the public actions in my project that accept a string as input.

Here is what I have tried:

```
var stringType = Types.Where(t => t.FullName == "System.String").Single();
var arTypes = Types.Where(t => t.FullName == "System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult").Single().DerivedTypes;

var results = 
from m in Methods
let DerivesFromAR = arTypes.Contains(m.ReturnType)
where m.ParameterTypes.Contains(stringType) && DerivesFromAR
select new { m.MethodId, m.Name, m.FullName };
```

I am using Nitriq because this seems like an ideal task for it, but I am open to other approaches (preferably not searching all of my methods by hand).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>You shouldn't be looking for types derived from `System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult`, but for types derived from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` as those classes contain methods that return action results.</strike>

Solution using `System.Reflection` and `System.Linq`, use from within of assembly that is supposed to be scanned

```
var controllerType = typeof(System.Web.Mvc.Controller);
var actionResultType = typeof(System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult);
var parameterType = typeof(string);

// find all controllers by checking their class
var controllers = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => controllerType.IsAssignableFrom(t));
// find all actions by checking their return type and parameter type
var actions = controllers.SelectMany(c => c.GetMethods()).Where(m => actionResultType.IsAssignableFrom(m.ReturnType) && m.GetParameters().Any(p => parameterType.IsAssignableFrom(p.ParameterType)));
```

Comment: I am new to Nitriq so I may be missing something (the fact that my query doesn't work demonstrates this), but it looks to me like I am testing the method return type against ActionResult.  Let me know if that looks mistaken.

Comment: Ignore anything I wrote except the code, which works. I'm really tired and misunderstood the code from nitriq.

Comment: Yes I was starting to think that going straight to Reflection was the way to go as well.  I love the idea of Nitriq but I am not sure that it is living up to it's potential. I will try your code shortly.

Answer (score 4):

I won't have a chance to check for sure until later today, but I think

```
var stringType = Types.Where(t => t.FullName == "System.Object").Single();
```

should be

```
var stringType = Types.Where(t => t.FullName == "System.String").Single();
```

It looks like right now you're looking for actions that take objects instead of actions that take strings.

Comment: Yes that was a stupid mistake.  Sadly however, no difference in result.  Will edit question.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote Nitriq, and at first glance I thought your query should work but after some testing I figured out why it wasn't returning the values you wanted.

First, your arTypes is only returning the derived types from `ActionResult` and not `ActionResult` itself. So theoretically your query would only return methods if it returned `JsonResult` which inherits from `ActionResult`. I said theoretically because the DerivedTypes collection on the Nitriq Type object only gets populated on assemblies that you've chosen to analyze and not dependent assemblies (like System.Web.Mvc). We did that to cut down on analysis time because most people don't care about what methods get called by their dependent assemblies otherwise they'd analyze the dependent assemblies too. However on retrospect, knowing the derived types of dependent assemblies is probably pretty useful and we'll likely change it in the future.

Assuming you don't want to add System.Web.Mvc to your Nitriq Project, you should be able to use a query like below to get what you want.

```
var stringType = Types.Where(t => t.FullName == "System.String").Single();
var arTypes = Types.Where(t => t.FullName == "System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult" || t.FullName == "System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult");

var results = 
from m in Methods
let DerivesFromAR = arTypes.Contains(m.ReturnType)
where m.ParameterTypes.Contains(stringType) && DerivesFromAR
select new { m.MethodId, m.Name, m.FullName };
```

If you do want to add System.Web.Mvc, you can find it at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll
```

In which case your new Nitriq Query should be:

```
var stringType = Types.Where(t => t.FullName == "System.String").Single();
var arTypes = Types.Where(t => t.FullName == "System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult").SelectMany(t => t.DerivedTypes);
var arType = Types.Where(t => t.FullName == "System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult").Single();

var results = 
from m in Methods
let DerivesFromAR = arTypes.Contains(m.ReturnType) ||  m.ReturnType == arType
where m.ParameterTypes.Contains(stringType) && DerivesFromAR
select new { m.MethodId, m.Name, m.FullName };
```

Comment: Thanks. I am on vacation now, but I will try that next week when I get back.